# Setting JavaScript Timeout limit in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is it possible to increase the time out limit for JavaScript?

If I have a script that executes for more than 20/30 seconds chrome will pop-up with the unresponsable page dialog.

Making a more efficient script won't help me because the script sometimes need to iterate through a function for a million or billion times

Comment: May I ask why you **need** to loop over a function a billion times? I have a feeling that the solution to this problem lies in optimizing your algorithm rather than increasing time limits.

Comment: I'm calculating the chances of getting different poker hands, which with 5 cards is 2598960 possibilities I need to loop over.

Comment: So then rather than looping over all those possibilities, why not apply some simple statistics properties/formulas? It seems like your calculations could make good use of the *Addition*, *Multiplication*, and *Conditional* probability formulas in particular.

Comment: I'm not that good at math and I let the user choose what cards are known, and how many cards in total

Comment: Ah, I see. Well if you're wanting lots of people to use this, you should definitely do some research into mathematical methods, as they'll be much more efficient, use lass hack-arounds, and provide an overall better experience. Perhaps this page would be of use to you: http://www.stats.gla.ac.uk/steps/glossary/probability.html#condprob

Comment: Does this have to work in IE? If your users can use FF/Chrome/Safari, you should use web workers, instead of the hack we suggested. http://ejohn.org/blog/web-workers/

Comment: Nope, it doesn't have to work in IE only Google Chrome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To split the function on steps/chunks and run those inside `setInterval(function(){})`.
This way page will be responsive, you will be able to notify user about progress of execution and you will get your job done.

**UPDATE**: Here is simple function that takes 
`worker` function executing each iteration, 
`chunksz` - number of iteration running in single chunk 
`maxit` - total number of iterations.

```
function task(worker, chunksz, maxit)
{
  var idx = 0;
  var xint = null;
  function exec_chunk() 
  {
     for(var n = 0; n < chunksz; ++n)
     {
       if(idx >= maxit) { return; }
       worker(idx++);
     }
     setTimeout(exec_chunk,1);
  }
  exec_chunk();
}
```

Here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/Ed9wL/ 
As you see you get all iterations in order.

**UPDATE2**:

Say you have a loop:

```
 for(var i=0; i<100000; ++i) { ... do something ... }
```

then you need to wrap body of the loop into a function and call the `task` above with it like this:

```
task(function(i){ ... do something ... },100, 100000);
```

or like this:

```
function loopBody(i){ ... do something ... }
task(loopBody,100, 100000);
```

Comment: See the comment on my own answer, and I need to loop through it in the right order, so I can't use 'setInterval(function(){})', but I'm using it at the beginning of the calculation.

Comment: I think he's saying to break up the loop into manageable chunks. So if you've already looped 10,000 times, then call setInterval() to let the browser know something's still happening. So with every loop, you could increment a counter. Then every time your counter hits 10,000, reset the counter and call setInterval() again.

Comment: I get the idea, but I don't know how to apply that to a recursive function

Comment: @Tylo: There is no recursive function there. See my UPDATE2.

Comment: @c-smile: It may not be stack recursion, but it is a type of recursion, a function that ends up calling itself until it's finished. The only difference is that it's done with a timeout.

Comment: @Juan Mendes: that was an answer on "I don't know how to apply that to a recursive function" - worker function is not recursive by itself.

Comment: @c-smile - your excellent task() function is not recursive (at least not by the definition I would use), but maybe Tyilo meant that his or her *original* function uses recursion and he or she is not sure how to make that work with your chunking algorithm.

Comment: @nnnnnn: the `task()` should work just fine in recursive cases too. I would make iteration count common for all `task()` invocations for such scenarios. I'll left it as an exercise for the reader.

By the way, such cases can naturally be handled using `yield` if it was implemented by all UA's.

Comment: Say I want to do this with your code: `function recursiveFunction(depth, num)
{
 if(depth == 10)
 {
  console.log(nums);
  return;
 }
 for(var a = num; a < 10; a++)
 {
  nums[depth] = a;
  recursiveFunction(depth + 1, a);
 }
}
var nums = [];
recursiveFunction(0, 0);`

Comment: @Tyilo: I tried to implement your recursive function with `task` but it doesn't make much sense to me, can you post an actual example of a recursive function you want to run (add documentation to explain what it's supposed to do), and how you call it? Don't post it as a comment like you did above, create a http://www.jsfiddle.net. @c-smile: I added an implementation of sumOfSquares using (a slightly modified) `task`, see my answer.

Comment: @Tyilo: You have to post something that works... What you posted doesn't do anything and you know it, missing globals. If your function is too complicated, you should create a reduction and post it. Please document your code, if it takes too much time to understand, I can't afford to help you.

Comment: @Tyilo, I tried something, it's still not clear what your function is supposed to do, but basically, you need to call the recursive function with a timeout. Since I don't know what your function is supposed to do, I don't know if the behavior has been affected. Test it out and let me know of any problems http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/9HKpb/1/  By the way, I think adding @Juan Mendes makes it notify the person that there's a comment they're interested in.

Comment: @Tyilo: funny guy, your function doesn't make sense to me, I know it didn't yield the same results but I'm not going to spend time debugging why it didn't. Had you properly documented your function as to what it's supposed to do, maybe I could have changed more of the logic to achieve the right result. In any case, that example gives you enough insight on how to break up your calculations with timeouts

Comment: Nope, not when working with recursive functions + for loops + global variables

Comment: @Tyilo: By the way, recursion with globals sounds really wrong

Answer (score 4):

If your goal is to suppress "Kill-Wait" message as quick temporary fix for your slow JavaScript then the solution is to open Tools/Developer Tools in Google Chrome and keep it open and minimized somewhere on your desktop while browsing .

Answer (score 3):

When you have lots of processing to do client side, you need to split out your work into separate threads. The browser only has a single thread for handling user input (events) and for processing JS. If you're processing too much JS, without yielding, the UI becomes unresponsive and the browser is not happy.

How can you allow your script to yield? The new way is to use web workers http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-workers/current-work/ . This works by creating a separate thread to run your JS, thread thread does not access to the DOM and can be run concurrently.

However, this newer technology doesn't exist in all browsers. For older browsers, you can split up your work by having the script call itself through timeouts. Whenever a timeout occurs, the script is yielding to the browser to run its events, once the browser is done, your next timeout will be triggered.

**Example** http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/PucXf/

```
var list = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
   list.push(Math.random());
}


function sumOfSquares(list) {  
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      total += list[i] * list[i];
      // DOM manipulation to make it take longer
      var node = document.createElement("div");
      node.innerHTML = "Sync temp value = " + total;
      document.body.appendChild(node);
  }
    return total;
}


function sumOfSquaresAsync(arr, callback) {
  var chunkSize = 1000; // Do 1000 at a time
  var arrLen = arr.length;
  var index = 0;
  var total = 0;  

  nextStep();

  function nextStep() {
     var step = 0;
     while (step < chunkSize && index < arrLen) {
       total += arr[index] * arr[index];
       // DOM manipulation to make it take longer
       var node = document.createElement("div");
       node.innerHTML = "Async temp value = " + total;
       document.body.appendChild(node);         
       index++;
       step++;
     }

     if (index < arrLen) {
        setTimeout(nextStep, 10);
     } else {
       callback(total);
     }
  }
}



sumOfSquaresAsync(list, function(total) {console.log("Async Result: " + total)});

//console.log("Sync result" + sumOfSquares(list));
```

The example on jsfiddle has the synchronous call commented out, you can put it back in to see the browser come to a crawl. Notice that the asynchronous call does take a long time to complete, but it doesn't cause the long running script message and it lets you interact with the page while calculating (select text, button hover effects). You can see it printing partial results on the pane to the bottom right.

**UPDATE** http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/PucXf/8/

Let's try to use c-smile's task function to implement sum of squares. I think he's missing a parameter, a function to call back when the task is finished. Using `task` allows us to create multiple chunked functions without duplicating the work of calling setTimeout and iteration.

```
/**
 * @param {function} worker. It is passed two values, the current array index, 
 *        and the item at that index
 * @param {array} list Items to be traversed
 * @param {callback} The function to call when iteration is finished;
 * @param {number} maxit The number of iterations of the loop to run 
 *        before yielding, defaults to 1000
 */
function task(worker, list, callback, maxit)
{
  maxit = maxit || 1000; 
  var idx = 0;
  exec_chunk();
  function exec_chunk() 
  {
     for(var n = 0; n < maxit; ++n)
     {
       if(idx >= list.length) {
         callback(); 
         return;
       }
       worker(idx, list[idx]);
       idx++;
     }
     setTimeout(exec_chunk,1);
  }
}


function sumOfSquaresAsync(list, callback) 
{
   var total = 0;

   // The function that does the adding and squaring
   function squareAndAdd(index, item) {
      total += item * item;
      // DOM manipulation to make it take longer and to see progress
      var node = document.createElement("div");
      node.innerHTML = "Async temp value = " + total;
      document.body.appendChild(node);                
   }

   // Let the caller know what the result is when iteration is finished
   function onFinish() {
      callback(total);
   }

   task(squareAndAdd, list, onFinish);

}

var list = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
   list.push(Math.random());
}

sumOfSquaresAsync(list, function(total) {
    console.log("Sum of Squares is " + total);        
})
```