# javascript crashes in a browser when running this script, what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, primes

I'm trying to solve a mathematical problem from http://projecteuler.net  using javascript: to find the sum of all the primes below two million. When I run the script I wrote, my browser crashes (I'm using Google Chrome). This is the script:

```
function isPrime(num) 
{ 
    if(num < 2) 
    return false; 
    for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) 
        { 
        if(num%i==0) 
        return false; 
        } 
return true; 
} 
var total=0e1;
    for (var i = 1; i < 2000000; i++)
        { 
        if(isPrime(i)) 
            {
            total=total+i;
            }
        } 

document.write("The sum of all the primes below two million is ",total);
```

The script works fine for smaller numbers (i<100000). What is wrong with it? How can I fix it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: probably a server timeout.. may need to up the timeout limit in .htaccess..

Comment: @McMastermind - this looks like a pure Javascript question. Why would the server be involved?

Comment: This is a heavy tight-loop. Likely it simply occupies your browser for a long time.

Comment: There are [better ways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) [to find primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), you know... Even changing your condition to test to up to `sqrt(num)` instead of `num` would greatly improve your performance. You're doing it the hardest way possible.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336844/setting-javascript-timeout-limit-in-google-chrome) It will show you ways to extend your run time in Chrome

Comment: On my 2.53 GHz Macbook Pro, your algorithm would take about two and a half hours to churn through the 2 mil tests. You could at least skip the even numbers once you pass 2 :)

Comment: @NullUserExeption I realize that this is not the simplest way, I'm just starting with javascript and I just wanted to practice what I've learnt so far.

Comment: @Julian Cheers, it's is not crashing any more. No I just need to wait :)

Comment: @lanzz I've changed to skip the even numbers, thanks :) now I'm gonna make a cup of tea and wait to find out how long it will take myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `isPrime` performs *n* modulo operations for each *n* you check (because you check every single number less than the prime as a factor). Assuming [about one in every seven numbers is prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem), that means you are performing the `isPrime` function about 28,000 times in your snippet, and you are performing [the modulo operation about 392 million times](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20of%20x%20from%200%20to%2028000). Likely, Chrome is crashing because it assumes the JavaScript engine has entered an infinite loop.

As NullUserException said, [there are better ways of finding primes.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

A naive improvement would be to only check for factors of a number that are less than its square root. For any number **a** where **a = b * c**, you can assume that either **b** or **c** is less than the square root of **a**. Since you only need to know one factor to know that a number is not prime, you only need to look for factors less than its square root. As lanzz commented, you can also skip even numbers.

```
function isPrime(n)
{
    if (n % 2) return false;       

    var s = Math.sqrt(n);

    // iterate by 2 to skip even numbers
    for (var i = 3; i <= s; i += 2)
        if (n % i) return false;

    return true;
}

var total = 3; // 1 + 2

// iterate by 2 to skip even numbers
for (var i = 3; i < 2000000; i += 2)
    if (isPrime(i)) total += i;
```

Don't mistake me; this won't change the *O* complexity of your algorithm, and you are still going to crash the JavaScript engine with a big enough number. But it will raise the number at which it crashes. I'm not sure if it will work up to 2 million.

Comment: @antonparker I changed to skip even numbers, and also extended run time in Chrome, but as you said, it will take a very long time.. I gave up after 20 odd minutes. I've modify the function isPrime to a different method and it worked with no time. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help. Like I said, my example didn't change the big O complexity and so my edits were only a small band-aid on the problem! Finding prime numbers efficiently is an active area of research in mathematics and there are lots of interesting ways to do it quickly.

Comment: @antonparker I've researched some ways to find primes, and so far only a few make sense to me, I'm just starting with javascript. Thanks again.

Comment: Your `isPrime()` function is completely broken. 1) The `for` loop only iterates over _even_ factors. 2) The `if` test condition incorrectly uses `s` instead of your `i` variable. Who upvoted this?

Comment: Whoops, fixed those. I edited the snippet several times and didn't test the edits. Regarding the upvote remark, I would assert that the post is helpful even with those errors. I have to ask why you didn't just edit the post to fix such a small portion of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Give this function a try, it uses a much faster algorithm than yours and it doesn't crash with the 2M number:

```
function isPrime( num ) {
    var testNum = 3;
    var limitNum = num;

    if ( num == 2 )
        return true;

    if ( num % 2 == 0 )
        return false;

    while ( limitNum > testNum ) {
        if ( num % testNum == 0 ) {
            return false;
        }

        limitNum = parseInt( num / testNum );
        testNum += 2;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I found it as VB code [here](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=1059), I just translated it to Javascript.

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you! I've changed the function and I got the result in no time :)

Comment: That's wrong. You mistranslated the code from the link. That has a `TestLimit` and that is set to `TestPrime / TestNum` (using `/` for integer division instead of VB's ``\``). If you change the candidate `num`, you'll get completely bogus results (try 35 e.g.: `35 % 3 != 0`, hence `num = parseInt(35/3) = 11`, `11 % 5 != 0`, hence `num = parseInt(11/5) = 2`, `2 < 7`, heya, `num` is prime!).

Comment: @DanielFischer you're absolutely right. I tried to shorten up the function and I missed that part. I just fixed it (I hope). Cheers!

Comment: Should be correct now. But usually, `while(testNum*testNum <= num)` is faster (divisions are slow, multiplications fast).

Comment: I didn't know that, I will certainly test it.