# JavaScript(jquery) function does not finish its excution

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a php file which returns a large json string (~2000 elements , each have 14 child element).
I use jquery ajax to fetch the json and put them in to id-identified table.
but it stops filling in mid-way(~1100).Here's the code:

```
var max = <?php echo $max; ?>; //max is the total number of elements in the database called by php.
$.ajax({
    url: "all_arr.php",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) { 
            $("#name_" + i).html(data[i].eng);
            $("#slot_" + i).html(data[i].slot);
        }
    }
});
```

---

**UPDATE:The code works fine in Safari,but not in chrome.**
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'eng' of undefined

Comment: There are lots of possible issues here. Have you checked the format of the response? Any errors in the console?

Comment: No Errors in the console.

Comment: Most likely cause is incorrectly formatted JSON at the point where it fails. Browsers handle JSON syntax errors differently - try it in say Firefox, IE and Chrome to see. You could also try [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: why you use `max` when you can exactly check how many values is returned by data.length or something?

Comment: @Seti agreed = max should be data.length - relying on a script generated value to determine the length of an AJAX response is not a good idea! :-)

Comment: It is not mal-formed Json because it stops at different points in different refreshes. May be something to deal with the memory limit?

Comment: You can add setTimeout(.., 0) for whole for block. It will derive it from the ajax execution - and then maybe it will work 100%? I had once similar issue with too long data from call.

Comment: @Seti Where to add the line? i am pretty new to jquery.

Comment: setTimeout(function () {        for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) { 
            $("#name_" + i).html(data[i].eng);
            $("#slot_" + i).html(data[i].slot);
        }}, 0);
sometimes it works sometimes not - but is worth a try.

Comment: @seti It does not work. But the code works fine in safari and error is found now:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'eng' of undefined

Comment: So some of your records gives bad data. switch `$("#name_" + i).html(data[i].eng);` with `if (typeof(data[i].eng) != "undefined") $("#name_" + i).html(data[i].eng);`  also you may use `hasOwnProperty` for checking that.  PS: Change the line for .slot accordinly

Comment: @Seti Again as same as the answer at the bottom, i think the problem do not come from the source JSON because of its randomness of stop. The method will be tried later coz i am out now

Comment: Used the answer in the following question and it worked.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336844/setting-javascript-timeout-limit-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 0):

How you get count of values in data table?:

```
var max = <?php echo $max; ?>; //max is the total number of elements in the database called by php.
```

It is wrong. You pass `data` parameter in your success function. Loop through it and receive all data this way.

Your final code will be (if data is array):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "all_arr.php",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
            $("#name_" + i).html(data[i].eng);
            $("#slot_" + i).html(data[i].slot);
        }
    }
});
```

Also, you can use this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "all_arr.php",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        var i;
        for (i in data) { 
            $("#name_" + i).html(data[i].eng);
            $("#slot_" + i).html(data[i].slot);
        }
    }
});
```

Both approaches based on length of received object in success function, but not on length you specified. Possibly, you set wrong length of data array, which you want to receive in this code: `var max = <?php echo $max; ?>;`.

Tell me about result.

Comment: Sorry but to mention that the json the i am calling is the whole table in database, so i use COUNT(*) in SQL to get the number of data.I could not figure out how to use data.length coz i am a noob. @Seti

Comment: @Seti I was writing answer (started ~8-9 mins ago, ended 6 mins ago), when you wrote your comment (8 mins ago), so I didn't saw it

Comment: @user2975716 It is not neccessary. Anyway you should use method which java script provides for you, but not using tricks, like you did.

Answer (score -1):

Please post the code for `all_arr.php` because the problem could be there.

- try the `error` paramenter if there is any errors:
- try the `max=2200` see if that works. max maybe set to wrong number in php.

.

```
var max = <?php echo $max; ?>;

$.ajax({
    url: "all_arr.php",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 10000, //add this if there a timeout
    success: function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            if(data[i] != undefined){
                $("#name_" + i).html(data[i].eng);
                $("#slot_" + i).html(data[i].slot);
            }
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

---

Timeout Error:

Your error event handler takes the three arguments `(xmlhttprequest, textstatus, message)` when a timeout happens, the `status` arg will be `timeout`. Then add:

```
timeout: 10000, //10seconds
```

---

Regarding your error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'eng' of undefined`
This is cleary an error in the `.php` file and what it returns.

```
if(data[i] != undefined){ // if nothing is returned, print nothing.
```

Comment: The problem still occur.

Comment: @user2975716 any alerts? did you replace `max` with 2200 just to try? can you post what `data` from `success: function(data)` return.  That code is correct your problem could be in your SQL.

Comment: but safari runs fine. Does it point to browser compatibility instead?

Comment: @user2975716 safari handles it better. chrome creates an error, does it work or not on chrome? the above answer?

Comment: Again i think that it is not mal-formed JSON because chrome stops randomly, not regularly. The method will need a try and i and out for now.